# How to remove pixel with an RGB value of 1,1,1?

Tags: compositing-nodes

Is there a node that would allow me to specifically remove pixels that have a 1,1,1 RGB value? Not looking for a ColorRamp, rather something that specifically targets the pixels by RGB value. Maybe a replacement node 1,1,1 -> 0,0,0 or a clamp node < 1,1,1. Thanks

Comment: Despeckle, maybe (compositor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way single node that will do this.  You can use a group of math nodes that will approximate it with shader nodes in various ways.  Here's one example of a math node group that does the approximation:

[image: Math node group to approximate replacing white with another color]

The left half of the group simply generates colors to test.  If it were plugged directly into the Principled shader it would make the lower half of the default cube red and the upper half white.

The group in the frame in the middle uses compare functions to see if the RGB value is *approximately* (1, 1, 1).  If it is, the output of the group is 1. If it is not, the output is 0.  This is the result you wanted.

You could plug the output into a combineRGB node, but I used a mix node instead.  With this technique you can replace white by any color of your choice.  Here I picked a shade of blue, but you could easily use black.

Here's what the default cube looks like without the node group

[image: Default cube using the output from the color ramp]

Here's what it looks like with the node group and the MixRGB node:

[image: Default cube using the output from the MixRGB node]

It's only *approximate* because the color values are floats and so the compare function has to deal with floating point representation.  I've set it to be accurate to 1 part in 1000.

Comment: Oh wow thank you. That's a lot more involved than I would have thought. I wonder if there is a way to do it in Python after the render using PIL...

Comment: The render image is available, so you would need some code to convert it to PIL, but you could probably process it and convert it back.  You might also do the same thing with Numpy, as the actual math is simply a loop substituting values for colors that are the numerical "white" for the render format.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing it in Python because I already had a post-processing script running after the render. I used the Pillow module and image.load() to retrieve an array of all pixels. It was trivial to loop across this 2 dimensional array to test and change the pixels one by one. I found out that the problem was not an RGB value of 1, 1, 1 but an RGBA value of 1, 1, 1, 1 for some isolated pixels due to a rendering artifact (I have a transparent background). So I tested for that last alpha value.